# Empathy doesn't connect to Facebook account

Tags: 10.10, empathy

Empathy worked pretty fine until last updates, now it refuses to connect to Facebook account. All other accounts work fine, except Facebook.

My username and password are 100% correct.
I'v tried to remove and add FB account, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Please help :)

Comment: Facebook has been recommending using Jabber/XMPP instead of the old facebook chat protocol. It's much more stable and there are way more clients which understand it. Here's how to use it: http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just being affected by facebook platform outages.  Empathy is working fine for me with facebook right now, but I get email notifications from the facebook platform team for outages.  I have gotten a bunch today, some of which talk about interuptions in the chat service.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, i used to have the same problem with Adium on OS X but it was fixed eventually. One thing i could recommend is downgrading to an older version of Empathy and see if that fixes the problem. Have you tried other IM's? Did they work?

Comment: yes, they do work fine

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a profile Badger for your Facebook account?

If you've made one, try to do this.
I'm not sure that this will work but no harm in trying.

Try to delete your Empathy settings folder in `~/.config/empathy` and probably delete this folder: `~/.gconf/apps/empathy`

It will make your Empathy back like new, and try to enter your account again.

If it does not work, try entering your Facebook user profile with a different user.

Comment: nope, doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. To fix it i uninstalled it via the package manager and then reinstalled it. It now works fine.

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

use this as username :

user@chat.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but fixed it in this way

In Empathy use the following preferences:

**What kind of chat account do you have?** Jabber
**What is your Jabber ID?** user.name@chat.facebook.com
**What is your Jabber Password?** use your own password