# Empathy no longer connects to Facebook

Tags: 12.04, empathy, facebook

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and it made me switch from Windows (irrelevant). I connected Empathy to my Facebook account and it worked really well for a couple of days, and all of the sudden it tells me "Authentication failed for account Facebook (xxxxxxxxx)". Is there a solution to fixing this problem?

Comment: This could be the result of a [service outage](http://askubuntu.com/a/7045/18612). How long have you been disconnected for? Try waiting a little while and see if the problem goes away on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Facebook has issues with messengers that isn't its own. I recommend giving it some time - in my experience it's usually back up and working within 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no solution.  Empathy worked fine for several years, even after upgrading to 13.04. Then after applying an update to a 12.10 system, empathy quite working on that system.  After applying an update to my 13.04 system, empathize would no longer connect to facebook on that system. I fixed my problem by removing empathy and installing pidgin. Pidgin works. The problem has something to to do with unity integration.